# Getting the object instance from a prototype

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to access an object's members from within an event function.  Sorry if I'm doing things wrong, I'm a beginner :)

I have something like this:

```
function MyObject( canvas )
{
    this.value  = 'Hello World';
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.canvas.addEventListener( 'mousemove', this.mouseMove );
}

MyObject.prototype.mouseMouse = function( evt )
{
    // this is the canvas
    var context = this.getContext( '2d' );
    context.fillText( /* how to get MyObject's value? */ , 0, 0 );
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The callback function needs to be called in the context of the object instance. For modern browsers you can use [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), which returns a function that is bound to a specific context:

```
this.canvas.addEventListener( 'mousemove', this.mouseMove.bind(this) );
```

In simpler terms, when `MyObject.prototype.mouseMove` gets called from `addEventListener`, the value of `this` within the function would be the `canvas` instance. You want the value of `this` to be the `MyObject` instance instead.

To get around this, we pass a function that is a wrapper for the function that we actually want to call. `this.mouseMove.bind(this)` creates a new function that wraps the `mouseMove` function so that the `this` value is the object instance instead of the canvas.

An alternative way of doing this is to create an anonymous function wrapper:

```
...
var self = this;
this.canvas.addEventListener( 'mousemove', function (e) {
    self.mouseMove(e);
} );
```

the disadvantage to this format is that you need to know how many arguments are passed to the function to pipe them through to the inner function call.

A way around this is with [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
var self = this;
this.canvas.addEventListener( 'mousemove', function () {
    //cast arguments to an array for cross-browser compatibility
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    return self.mouseMove.apply(self, args);
} );
```

Now if you write that kind of code a lot you'll realize that there's an easy way to abstract out the variables, all you need is a function and a context and you can generate a wrapper. That's what `Function.prototype.bind` does.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options to preserve `MyObject` context inside event listener. `bind` is the one and here is another:

```
function MyObject(canvas) {
    this.value  = 'Hello World';
    this.canvas = canvas;

    var self = this;
    this.canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
        self.mouseMove(e);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple and it looks like you already understand!

`this.value`

Comment: In the context of the event function, "this" is the canvas

Comment: I may have misunderstood the question, but the `mouseMouse` method cannot be called on the canvas property of the constructor, only the object instantiated from the constructor (because it is on the constructor's prototype).